# How to convert a string to a JSON array using NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

In NiFi I'm processing a flowfile containing the following attribute:

```
Key: 'my_array'
    Value: '[u'firstElement', u'secondElement']'
```

I'd like to split flowFile on this array to process each element separately (and then merge). I tried to use `SplitJson` processor, but it requires JSON content to operate on, so  I used `AttributesToJSON` before it. Unfortunately the produced flowFile's content is:

```
{"my_array": "[u'firstElement', u'secondElement'"}
```

And I receive the error

> The evaluated value [u'firstElement', u'secondElement'] of $['my_array'] was not a JSON Array compatible type and cannot be split.

Is it possible to convert `my_array` string to the correct JSON array? Do I need to use `ExecuteScript` or is there some simpler way?

Comment: the `[u'firstElement', u'secondElement']` has not a valid json format. i think it's a kind of python formatting.

Comment: Yes, these values come from Python, but I think that the main problem is having `"[u'firstElement', u'secondElement']"` instead of `[u'firstElement', u'secondElement']`

Comment: with doublequotes - it's just a string. without - not a valid json. could you produce json from python?

Comment: I tried to convert it to the list in Python, but it causes error `org.python.core.PyList cannot be cast to java.lang.String `, so it seems that Python script has to return string.

Comment: use `json.dumps(...)` to convert python data to json-formatted string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `ReplaceText` with `Replacement Strategy` of `Always Replace` and `Replacement Value` of `${my_array}` and then `SplitJSON`?
This will replace your FlowFile's content with this attribute's value and then you could `SplitJSON` on it.

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution along with the one proposed by @dagett. I changed Python script to set `json.dumps(...)` as attribute's value and than I put `ReplaceText` with`Replacement Value = {"my_array": ${my_array}}`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I want to string : "Hashtags": "['tag1','tag2']" (a*s part of my resultant json in Nifi,*) to be changed into : "Hashtags": ['tag1','tag2'].

what I do is :

[image: Apache Nifi replaceText sample]

I use ReplaceText with `Replacement Strategy : Regex Replace` and `Replacement Value : a regex Expression`.  This will replace FlowFile's matched content with this attribute's value and then you could continue your process.

Comment: That does indeed work, thanks for the tip.  It sucks that NiFi doesn't properly format JSON lists in AttributesToJson processor, instead it turns them into strings.