# How to convert String value to array in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-nifi

all.

I have a query in a `ExecuteSQLRecord` processor which produces a JSON column in the result:

```
SELECT t.id, json_agg(json_build_object("value1", t.column1, "value2", t.column2)) AS "test" FROM table t GROUP BY t.id
```

The processor uses a `JSONRecordSetWriter` to write the results. However, the processor returns a String from the database, which causes issues in further processing that expects a JSON value:

```
{
   ...
   "test": "[{\"value1\": \"column1value\", \"value2\": \"column2value\"}, ...]"
}
```

Is there a way of turning it to a proper JSON value, i.e., in this format:

```
{
   ...
   "test": [{"value1": "column1value", "value2": "column2value"}, ...]
}
```

without resorting to `ReplaceText` processors?

I have tried to replace the quotes in the SQL query, to use `jsonb_agg()` and `jsonb_build_object()`, and to use a `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` but none worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't build json on the level of database. Or do it fully on the level of database. Your current problem could be solved with scripting.

Comment: You might look into JOLT but I think that would require Nifi be interpreting the string as JSON as a precondition.  Not sure what database you're using but there might be some regex functions available in SQL as well to format it.  MongoDB might be a better more native option for JSON data storage than an RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks @daggett, but some of the values themselves are already JSONs...

Comment: Thanks @firefly2442, I couldn't do it with JOLT due to the reason you mentioned. It's not an option to change the database now, but I appretiate the suggestion... I guess I'll have to stick with the `ReplaceText`s for now.

Comment: i can show how to script it with groovy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404894/1743724